# TLS version usage statistics from Mozilla Firefox

Tags: https, firefox

does anyone know if the data for TLS version usage statistics (what percentage of connections is established using 1.1, 1.2, 1.3) are somewhere public?
For example I have noticed that Mozilla has this telemetry site https://telemetry.mozilla.org/ but most of the stuff seems to not be public. Does anyone know if it is possible to read the data from there somehow?
I know about annual reports that some companies make on this topic but I am more interested in a up-to-date statistic source.

Comment: Various browsers/hosters provide irregularly some statistics, for example https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2018/10/15/removing-old-versions-of-tls/ in 2018. Besides the fact that your question might be offtopic here, "up-to-date statistic source" might be difficult: from which viewpoint? From browsers, you have only the people using it; from web hosters you have only data about websites they host, so in neither cases you can have a full picture on what happens on the Internet.

Comment: Questions seeking [recommendations for sites and resources](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are considered off-topic here since they can result in self-promotional answers and often become out-of-date.